# Right way to use boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost

I see two ways of accessing a `boost::optional` variable:

1. The dereference operator on the variable
2. The variable itself

If I have this code snippet:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::optional<int> oi;
  std::cout << oi << "\n";
}
```

(where oi is uninitialized) and compile it using "`g++-4.9 /tmp/optional.cc`" followed by `./a.out`, I get 0,

but with this:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::optional<int> oi;
  std::cout << *oi << "\n";
}
```

I get:

```
a.out: /usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:631: boost::optional<T>::reference_type boost::optional<T>::get() [with T = int; boost::optional<T>::reference_type = int&]: Assertion `this->is_initialized()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

which is the expected behavior.

Comment: I predict the first doesn't compile with C++11.

Comment: @chris Depends on the version of boost you are using.

Comment: @T.C., Of course it does :/ I was looking at the docs for 1.57.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it does compile with both C++11 and C++14. Wonder why it isn't caught by the compiler?                                                   Also, it does seem like the behavior is defined when dereferencing an uninitialized boost::optional (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_operator_asterisk). It says the requirement is asserted via a BOOST_ASSERT().

Comment: Before the internals of Boost.Optional actually cause UB, the assertion aborts execution, provided assertions are not disabled. So yes, your program aborts without UB, while in an optimized build without assertions will invoke UB. I'd still say "it causes UB" though, even if some add-on (the assertion) detected that before it actually happened.

Comment: Agreed and that's a great explanation re: UB. On that note, are the default boost development packages (like say on Ubuntu), built with assertions enabled?

Comment: I hope not, because I wouldn't want to pay the additional performance penalty. However, last I looked, Boost.Optional was header-only, so it only depends on your compile settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have been using an older version of Boost. Your first case triggered a conversion to `bool`; since the `optional` does not contain a value, the result of the conversion is `false`, which is printed as `0`.

Newer versions (1.56-1.57) added an `operator<<` function template declaration to `<boost/optional.hpp>`

```
template<class CharType, class CharTrait, class T>
std::basic_ostream<CharType, CharTrait>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharType, CharTrait>& out, optional<T> const& v);
```

to catch this kind of mistakes and cause a linker error instead.

Note that including `<boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>` allows you to actually use the stream operators with `optional`, in which case `optional`s that do not contain a value are printed as `--`.

Comment: Ah ok. I have 1.55 on my machine. Thanks a bunch for the replies though. This has been very useful. I 'll stick to using the dereference operator.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::optional<T>` ostream helpers are actually available since boost 1.34. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/boost/optional/optional_io.hpp

Note that one needs to *EXPLICITLY* include `<boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>` to enable these helpers. It is *NOT* included by `<boost/optional.hpp>`.